# Rails. Write/Update from controller the second model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I've got two models: Client and Vlan. I need to mark Vlan as "active" when "f.select" it from view by creating "Client".
Here some code from models:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :vlans
end

class IP < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
end
```

Made a migration (probably wrong way):

```
class AddClientIdToIPs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_belongs_to :vlans, :client
  end
end
```

And have a client_id in Vlan-model, and vlan_id in the Client-model.

In clients_controller I've:

```
def create
    @client = Client.new(client_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @client.save
        format.html { redirect_to clients_path, notice: 'Success.' }
        #format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @client }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @client.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

By creating "Client" I successfuly select vlan and it updates in DB(as vlan_id), but I have to see which client is binded to vlan, so I have to write/update a client_id in Vlan-model.

How to do it ? I think my migration/assosiation ways are wrong, but maybe controllers are wrong too.